# SQL CONCAT - Funny characters - but I'm not laughing

Tags: mysql, sql, collation, concatenation

I am using this query to produce a blog archive menu, like so:

```
SELECT CONCAT( MONTHNAME(published) , ' ' , YEAR(published)) AS monthyear, 
COUNT(*) AS total
FROM blog_articles
WHERE status = 'Online' AND Year(published) = 2012
GROUP BY CONCAT( MONTHNAME(published) , ' ' , YEAR(published))
```

Expected result:

```
January 2012        103
February 2012       87
March 2012          23
April 2012          99
```

Actual result:

[image]

The count is correct but instead of the mental oriental, it should read:

```
May 2012       1
```

How can I get rid of the funny characters and have English instead?

When I run this query in phpMyAdmin, the characters are fine.

**UPDATE**

I have just tried running conn.Execute("SET lc_time_names = 'en_US';") and didn't solve the problem. To check, I used conn.Execute("SELECT @@lc_time_names;") and it returned "en_US".

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Searching on MySQL forums for related issues, I found another guy whining about the same issue. A MySQL guru said:

> "This is the famous (infamous) server returns wrong types for CONCAT
>   of a number and a string. One has to use the (cast) form for this to
>   work, the driver can't tell what the real type is."

I'm not sure what cast is or how to fix this issue.

Comment: + 1 for title :P

Comment: +1 for "mental oriental" `:P`.

Comment: What is the *most trivial* query that reproduces the issue of "funny"  characters? The above query is 1. either the minimal query (which should be specified) or; 2. contains a bunch of unnecessary SQL (`GROUP BY`, `CONCAT`, `MONTHNAME`, etc).

Comment: For instance, what does `SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(published), '-') FROM blog_articles` return?

Comment: @pst: It returns "May-".

Comment: @PaparazzoKid So at what point does the the query *stop* working? (Build it back up until the breaking-point-bottom is found and then tear it back down until the breaking-point-top is found.)

Comment: Oh... I just ran that query through phpMyAdmin, which was okay in the first place. I will try that in my code now..

Comment: @PaparazzoKid If it's just in your *code*, then it may be a *per-connection* locale setting that is wonky? E.g. do any queries work? If so, which one(s)? If not, which one(s)? And, how do they differ?

Comment: @pst: Right, I have "May-" in my code too. So I need to rebuild this query from here?

Comment: Okay, the problem comes from using the CONCAT function. When I use it, it returns "funny", when I don't, it's "not funny". I'm not sure why I was using it in the first place to be fair. I know the year "2012", so I have just removed the whole CONCAT thing and adding the year in my code. I'm still baffled as to why this was happening tho', for future reference...

Comment: @pst: I have just gone through some old MySQL issues on the MySQL forums. I haven't found a fix for this but think it's a problem using CONCAT with letters and numbers, for example, concatenating a month name with a year (February+2012). Apparently MySQL gets confused as to what the actual "type" is. My latest question update shows what this MySQL expert wrote in the forum about this problem.

Comment: See cast() example and function link in answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Silly server, math is for numbers.

`CAST()`  [CAST(enum_col AS CHAR)   - cast a value as a certain type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

```
 SELECT CONCAT( CAST(MONTHNAME(published) as char) , ' ' , CAST(YEAR(published)) as char) AS monthyear, 
 COUNT(*) AS total
 FROM blog_articles
 WHERE status = 'Online' AND Year(published) = 2012
 GROUP BY CONCAT( MONTHNAME(published) , ' ' , YEAR(published))
```

`DATE_FORMAT()` You might also try DATE_FORMAT(YEAR(published), '%Y') function instead of CAST.

Comment: Just noticed I didn't put CAST() in the GROUP BY!

Comment: That's okay, I noticed and put it in. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you have a lc_time_names set "funny".

Try:

SET lc_time_names = 'en_US';

before running the query.

Comment: Haha "funny". I have just tried this and didn't solve the problem unfortunately. To check, I used conn.Execute("SELECT @@lc_time_names;") and it returned "en_US". Any ideas?

Comment: SELECT MONTHNAME('2012-05-05')   exhibits the same effect?

Answer (score 5):

Switch your locale to English then.  The following is also SQL.

```
SET lc_time_names = 'en_US';
```

[From here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/locale-support.html).

Comment: I have just tried this and didn't solve the problem. To check, I used conn.Execute("SELECT @@lc_time_names;") and it returned "en_US". Any ideas?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid - When starting `mysqld`, specify `--skip-character-set-client-handshake` option.  BTW please tag your question with your operating system.